# How do I convert jstring to wchar_t *

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Let's say that on the C++ side my function takes a variable of type `jstring` named `myString`. I can convert it to an ANSI string as follows:

```
const char* ansiString = env->GetStringUTFChars(myString, 0);
```

is there a way of getting

`const wchar_t* unicodeString =` ...

Answer (score 13):

If this helps someone... I've used this function for an Android project:

```
std::wstring Java_To_WStr(JNIEnv *env, jstring string)
{
    std::wstring value;

    const jchar *raw = env->GetStringChars(string, 0);
    jsize len = env->GetStringLength(string);
    const jchar *temp = raw;
    while (len > 0)
    {
        value += *(temp++);
        len--;
    }
    env->ReleaseStringChars(string, raw);

    return value;
}
```

An improved solution could be (Thanks for the feedback):

```
std::wstring Java_To_WStr(JNIEnv *env, jstring string)
{
    std::wstring value;

    const jchar *raw = env->GetStringChars(string, 0);
    jsize len = env->GetStringLength(string);

    value.assign(raw, raw + len);

    env->ReleaseStringChars(string, raw);

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Neat, though I suspect loading the wstring with a buffer in one go would be more efficient that one character at a time.

Comment: Does the C++ compiler notice that you are returning an automatic, and allocate it on the heap and not the stack?

Answer (score 4):

JNI has a GetStringChars() function as well.  The return type is const jchar*, jchar is 16-bit on win32 so in a way that would be compatible with wchar_t.  Not sure if it's real UTF-16 or something else...

Comment: Do you happen to know if jchar's byte ordering is compatible with the Win32 wchar_t one? It should be, but probably good to be sure. :-)

Comment: jchar is typedef'ed to unsigned short.  I haven't tried it myself but my guess would be "yes".

Comment: char == jchar == unsigned 16 bits

Comment: char == unsigned 16 bits on which platform?

Comment: To keep this a little less confusing, in this discussion "char" is the built-in data type in the ISO C and C++ languages, not in Java.

Comment: If jchar is unsigned short then it means it is 16bit. So wchar_t is also an unsigned short so 16bit. In conclusion jchar x = wchar_t y ;)

Answer (score 4):

And who frees wsz?
I would recommend STL!

```
std::wstring JavaToWSZ(JNIEnv* env, jstring string)
{
    std::wstring value;
    if (string == NULL) {
        return value; // empty string
    }
    const jchar* raw = env->GetStringChars(string, NULL);
    if (raw != NULL) {
        jsize len = env->GetStringLength(string);
        value.assign(raw, len);
        env->ReleaseStringChars(string, raw);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Not a great solution unless using C++11 since the wstring will be returned by value.  (Obviously post C++11 it'll be move constructed which would be efficient)

Comment: value.assign(raw, len); is not valid. I think it should be value.assign(raw, raw + len); but I haven't tested yet.

Comment: Great - worked for me perfectly in a C# -> C++/CLI -> JNI -> Java application!

Comment: Don't you have to call ReleaseStringChars regardless of success of GetStringChars otherwise the jstring may be pinned and 'leak'

Answer (score 3):

A portable and robust solution is to use [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/), with the understanding that you have to know what encoding your system `wchar_t` uses (UTF-16 on Windows, UTF-32 on many Unix systems, for example).

If you want to minimise your dependency on third-party code, you can also hand-roll your own UTF-8 converter. This is easy if converting to UTF-32, somewhat harder with UTF-16 because you have to handle surrogate pairs too. :-P Also, you must be careful to reject [non-shortest](http://www.google.com/search?q=utf-8+non-shortest) forms, or it can open up security bugs in some cases.

Comment: You're suggesting converting the jstring to UTF-8 then back to UTF-16? Is that really necessary?

Comment: @Rup jstrings already are UTF-8: "The JNI uses modified UTF-8 strings to represent various string types. Modified UTF-8 strings are the same as those used by the Java VM. Modified UTF-8 strings are encoded so that character sequences that contain only non-null ASCII characters can be represented using only one byte per character, but all Unicode characters can be represented.....The Java VM does not recognize the four-byte format of standard UTF-8; it uses its own two-times-three-byte format instead."

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy Really? jni.h on my system (both 1.6 and 1.7) has `typedef unsigned short jchar;` which looks more like UTF-16 to me.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something then, that quote was pulled directly from Oracle's documentation: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html) Feel free to explain if you can, I'm still trying to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 3):

I know this was asked a year ago, but I don't like the other answers so I'm going to answer anyway.  Here's how we do it in our source:

```
wchar_t * JavaToWSZ(JNIEnv* env, jstring string)
{
    if (string == NULL)
        return NULL;
    int len = env->GetStringLength(string);
    const jchar* raw = env->GetStringChars(string, NULL);
    if (raw == NULL)
        return NULL;

    wchar_t* wsz = new wchar_t[len+1];
    memcpy(wsz, raw, len*2);
    wsz[len] = 0;

    env->ReleaseStringChars(string, raw);

    return wsz;
}
```

**EDIT**: This solution works well on platforms where wchar_t is 2 bytes, some platforms have a 4 byte wchar_t in which case this solution will not work.

Comment: This solution is wrong. I sucked 12 hours because of that.
wchar_t and jchar are not necessary the same.
The proof for that is the output of my test program:

`01-26 20:28:43.675: E/[LMI-NATIVE](9280): len: 7, jchar: 2, wchar: 4`

Comment: @Kobor42 - What does your test program do?  Are you saying that you found an instance where wchar_t was 4 bytes?  I didn't actually realise it but this function was designed to run (primarily) on Windows where wchar_t is always 2.  I now realise wchar_t is compiler specific and may be different on your platform.

Comment: Exactly. On Android prior 2.1 wchar_t is 1 byte. 2.1 and after is 4 bytes.

Comment: You're mixing potentially incompatible types. A Java `jchar` is always UTF-16. But `wchar_t` is not always UTF-16, sometimes it is UTF-32. In such cases you need to convert UTF-16 to UTF-32 (it's NOT just a matter of padding jchar to 4 bytes, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16 for details).

Comment: I'm not mixing it. NDK is mixing it. I would like to convert java strings wihout information loss to c strings.

Comment: @Benj - Why it does not work on platform with wchar_t  as 4 bytes ?

Answer (score 1):

If we are not interested in cross platform-ability, in windows you can use the MultiByteToWideChar function, or the helpful macros A2W (ref. [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2008/07/24/visual-c-in-short-converting-between-unicode-and-utf-8.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Just use env->GetStringChars(myString, 0);
Java pass Unicode by it's nature

Answer (score 0):

Rather simple. But do not forget to free the memory by ReleaseStringChars

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_TestClass_test(JNIEnv * env, jobject, jstring string)
{
    const wchar_t * utf16 = (wchar_t *)env->GetStringChars(string, NULL);
    ...
    env->ReleaseStringChars(string, utf16);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to jstring->char->wchar_t

```
char* js2c(JNIEnv* env, jstring jstr)
{
    char* rtn = NULL;
    jclass clsstring = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
    jstring strencode = env->NewStringUTF("utf-8");
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(clsstring, "getBytes", "(Ljava/lang/String;)[B");
    jbyteArray barr = (jbyteArray)env->CallObjectMethod(jstr, mid, strencode);
    jsize alen = env->GetArrayLength(barr);
    jbyte* ba = env->GetByteArrayElements(barr, JNI_FALSE);
    if (alen > 0)
    {
        rtn = (char*)malloc(alen + 1);
        memcpy(rtn, ba, alen);
        rtn[alen] = 0;
    }
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(barr, ba, 0);
    return rtn;
}

jstring c2js(JNIEnv* env, const char* str) {
    jstring rtn = 0;
    int slen = strlen(str);
    unsigned short * buffer = 0;
    if (slen == 0)
        rtn = (env)->NewStringUTF(str);
    else {
        int length = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, (LPCSTR)str, slen, NULL, 0);
        buffer = (unsigned short *)malloc(length * 2 + 1);
        if (MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, (LPCSTR)str, slen, (LPWSTR)buffer, length) > 0)
            rtn = (env)->NewString((jchar*)buffer, length);
        free(buffer);
    }
    return rtn;
}



jstring w2js(JNIEnv *env, wchar_t *src)
{
    size_t len = wcslen(src) + 1;
    size_t converted = 0;
    char *dest;
    dest = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    wcstombs_s(&converted, dest, len, src, _TRUNCATE);

    jstring dst = c2js(env, dest);
    return dst;
}

wchar_t *js2w(JNIEnv *env, jstring src) {

    char *dest = js2c(env, src);
    size_t len = strlen(dest) + 1;
    size_t converted = 0;
    wchar_t *dst;
    dst = (wchar_t*)malloc(len * sizeof(wchar_t));
    mbstowcs_s(&converted, dst, len, dest, _TRUNCATE);
    return dst;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I converted `jstring` to `LPWSTR`.

```
const char* nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(javaString, 0);
size_t size = strlen(nativeString) + 1;
LPWSTR lpwstr = new wchar_t[size];
size_t outSize;
mbstowcs_s(&outSize, lpwstr, size, nativeString, size - 1);
```